# How to use the object oriented language Swift the right way?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, swift2

I'm new in Swift and even in object oriented programming languages itself. So my question is, how to use this very extensive language Swift the right way? I give an example to verify my problem:

Let's say I have got two classes:

1. Class ScanForBluetoth{} //Handles all parts to scan for BT devices

   ```
   class ScanForDevices: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate , CBPeripheralDelegate, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{}
   ```
2. Class Bluetooth{} //Handles only the Bluetooth parts with it's delegates

   ```
   class Bluetooth: ScanForDevices{}
   ```

Now, I would like to implement all my used delegates and other Bluetooth specific functions into the Bluetooth class. BUT I need some objects (for example of the CBCentralManagerDelegate) in my ScanForDevices class, too. So, I have to implement all my delegates in my "mother" class ScanForDevices although I only need some properties. SO if I implement the delegates, I have to be conform with the protocol and must implement ALL my needed delegate functions... At the end I have implemented all my delegate functions in ScanForDevices and then override them in Bluetooth. But I don't think that my way is the best way to realize this problem...
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would like to point out that your naming conventions are really off. In object oriented programming, you want your class names to be *objects* (nouns). You named your classes by what they were doing, rather than what they are. A better name choice for your classes would be something like BluetoothDeviceScanner, rather than scan for devices, and BluetoothManager rather than the non-explicit "bluetooth".

Secondly, what you have done is *subclassed* the bluetooth class to scan for devices class, which causes it to inherit all the functionality of its class. This really doesn't make any sense. Subclassing is used to create an object based on a parent object, while these two objects handle two totally different things, and then you're planning on overriding the functions anyway. Instead of that, you should just include the protocols that you need in the bluetooth class separately. Keep the functionality of the two classes separated as much as possible.

Thirdly, you should separate your view controller functionality from the scanning functionality. What I mean is the "ScanForDevices" object's job is to scan for devices, so it shouldn't also have the job of controlling a view... I would remove the UIViewController protocol and introduce a new view controller class, and within that class you can have a property that is assigned the "ScanForDevices" object, at which point the devices can be scanned for within the viewcontroller, but the scanning functionality is contained within a single object (which is best practice).

---

### EDIT

All you need to do to "connect" the data is have your BluetoothManager and BluetoothScanner objects is have them available as a property within whatever view controller you need them. So, in the viewcontroller declare some properties, I usually do it with optionals so that I don't have to worry about initializing the properties (This means you need to *unwrap* the variables before using them).
In your ViewController...

```
var bluetoothScanner: BluetoothScanner?
var bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager?

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    bluetoothScanner = BluetoothScanner(init parameters)
    bluetoothManager = BluetoothManager(init parameters)

}
```

You're objects are now "connected" in the sense that you have access to them and all their properties/methods in the viewcontroller. Now that I think about it, you don't even need to have both objects on this level. You can store the BluetoothScanner as a property of the Bluetooth manager, at which point you would only need to use a BluetoothManager object to handle all your bluetooth needs on the view controller level.

---

### Init Methods

```
//init method that takes 2 parameters, a string and a uiviewcontroller.
init(param1: String, param2: UIViewController) {
    //Struct init code using parameters
    self.name = param1
    self.viewController = param2
}

//init method that takes no parameters, but still initializes the same properties.
init() {
    self.name = "YungGun"
    self.viewController = UIViewController()
}
```

Keep in mind these initialization methods are made up and have nothing to do with your problem at hand, I was attempting to illustrate that this is where you define the parameters needed to initialize the struct. The same parameters in the parenthesis must be passed when creating an instance of the struct.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer. The first and the third point make sense for me and I will change them directly. But there is one more question to your second point. How am I able to "connect" two classes? My Bluetooth class will create a struct which saves the discovered BT devices. So how can I get this data in ScanForDevices?

Comment: Just to be clear, do not use the name ScanForDevices as a name, but rather something like BluetoothDeviceScanner (again names should be *nouns*). The connecting of the data would be done at a higher level. There are different ways it can be done, but in iOS/Swift most likely do it within a controller object, such as a view controller or a navigation controller. I'll add some code to show you a way of doing it.

Comment: Ah okay, I used the old names to make clear what I would like to say. I will change them as fast as possible ;) but give me one more hint. What do you mean with "init parameters"? do I have to init all parameters at that time? or how can I reach the "CBperipheral" object for example from my bluetoothManager Class? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The init parameters refers to the parameters needed to initialize those specific objects, which depends on how you yourself set up those objects. Accessing the peripheral can be done by having the peripheral as property within the bluetooth manager, which is a task in its own to set up. I'll add examples of inits to my original post.